# AIOHTTP OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address

Tags: aiohttp

I have an aiohttp web server that occasionally crashes and fails to release the port. I uses a process manager to restart the python application when it quits, but occasionally it fails to release the port and the result is that when the aiohttp server tries to start up again, an OS error is generated(`OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 8080)`)

Is there a way to handle this error directly?  My issue is that this error is swallowed by the `aiohttp` server and the service never crashes.

In my case, this is because I'm used another framework (database) that uses the aio event loop and that other service keeps the loop running.  `aiohttp` seems to assume it's the only application using the event loop and that when it errors out that the event loop will stop -- but in my case it keeps humming right along, not accepting requests and not erroring out.

Comment: PS. Related questions are asking why this error happens. I know why it happens and want to instead know how to properly handle the error (i.e. run code when it happens).